# Apply a scalar VBA function to each cell in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a VBA function that performs a numerical computation, e.g.:

```vb
Function MyFunc(ByVal x As Double, ByVal a As Double) As Double
    MyFunc = x + a
End Function
```

I want to use a worksheet formula to apply this function to an array and sum the values. For example, in cell `B1` I would like to enter:

```
=SUM(MyFunc(A1#, 2))
```

with the meaning of (if `A1#` is the dynamic array `A1:A3`):

```
=SUM(MyFunc(A1,2), MyFunc(A2,2), MyFunc(A3,2))
```

Can I do this without having to explicitly write the array loop in my VBA function?

Comment: I don't believe so... you'll get a type mismatch as soon as you pass an array as the first argument.

Comment: @FaneDuru, what do you mean by "An UDF function cannot use the Target cell value in its calculations"? The function above works when applied to single cells (rather than arrays).

Comment: @BigBen, if I try I get indeed an error. But if instead of `MyFunc` I use a built-in function then it works. I could change MyFunc to loop over `x` and return an array, but I have several such functions and if possible I would prefer to avoid repeating the boilerplate loop in each of them.

Comment: Because built-in functions are built to handle arrays.

Comment: @BigBen: Upsss. He is right, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a spill-down to a UDF, you can pass it as a `Range`:

```
Function MyFunc(x As Range, a As Double)
    Dim L As Long, U As Long, arr, i As Long
    Dim r As Range
    L = 1
    U = x.Count
    ReDim arr(L To U)

    For i = L To U
        arr(i) = x(i) + a
    Next i
    MyFunc = arr
End Function
```

So in the worksheet in cell **C1** we put:

```
=myfunc(A1#,8)
```

As you see, it spills across, and in **C2** we put:

```
=SUM(myfunc(A1#,8))
```

[image]

As you see, we give it a `Range`; it returns an `Array` which `SUM()` can easily handle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Evaluate in combination with range:

```
Function MyFunc1(x As Range, ByVal a As Double) As Variant
    MyFunc1 = Application.Evaluate("(" & x.Address & "+" & a & ")")
End Function
```

And directly summed:

```
Function MyFunc1(x As Range, ByVal a As Double) As Variant
    MyFunc1 = Application.Evaluate("SUM(" & x.Address & "+" & a & ")")
End Function
```